# Why is my document.Add(paragraph) not working (wpf, iText)?

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf using iText in WPF. But I am not able to add any paragraphs to my document.
Here's my code:

```
        string destination = "po.pdf";
        var fos = File.Create(destination);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "hello"
        });

        document.Add(p1);
        document.Close();
    }
```

Here, in the second last line (document.Add(p1)), I get a red underline under 'p1'.
The error says --- Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph' to 'iText.Layout.Element.AreaBreak'.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph in not part of itext. you must use Paragraph  from itext namespace

Comment: In other words, check your `using`s, they may point to the wrong namespaces.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. It worked :)

Comment: Hey @Xilmiki, can you please help me out with the following question too? ----- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866637/is-there-any-way-to-apply-same-style-to-multiple-table-cells-in-itext7

Comment: Hey @mkl, can you please help me out with the following question too? -----https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866637/is-there-any-way-to-apply-same-style-to-multiple-table-cells-in-itext7